# Installation of ngAnimate Module not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I can't seem to get ng-animate to work in an existing 1.2 application. I've followed the check list in the API, but it isn't applying the appropriate animate classes.

I feel like I must be missing something silly in the installation process. Here's what I've done:

1 - I'm loading angular and angular-animate in the head of my document here:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script> <!-- load angular -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-animate.js"></script> <!-- load angular animate -->
```

2 - I am adding the module as a dependency in my app declaration here:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['mainCtrl', 'mainService', 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'sortable', 'services.breadcrumbs']);
```

And that's it! It should be working right? All I get when using **ng-show** is the **ng-hide** class. I was expecting to get the ng-hide-add and ng-hide-remove classes as well, but nothing has changed.

What am I missing? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this should count as an answer, but it works just fine if I use angular's beta release (1.3.0-beta.5). I still would like to know why the stable release is not working properly, but the beta release is...

Answer (score 1):

Set CSS rules to handle the animations; otherwise, you won't see the changes you're expecting to the class as you inspect the element.

Example:

```
.ng-hide-add,
.ng-hide-remove {
  transition:0.5s linear all;

  display:block!important;
  opacity:1;
}
.ng-hide {
  opacity:0;
}
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3UGA2tYnzc1pNZyICMph?p=preview)

Comment: Marc, I've already set up css rules like this, but they aren't doing anything because the classes "ng-hide-add" and "ng-hide-remove" are not even being appended to the object. Not sure what I could have done wrong...

Comment: The reason I wrote this answer was: if you don't set the CSS rules, those classes won't be added/removed in the first place. Check out the Plunker I included in my answer, and you'll see that animations are working using the versions you've provided. Compare your code to it and see if there are any obvious differences.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know that. +1 Marc and thank ya :). Unfortunately, it still doesn't wanna work on my app unless I use the beta version. I tried copying your css rules to my doc, and I still am not seeing any changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with `ui-view` instead of `ng-view`, you might have to add `ng-animate-children attribute` to the `ui-view` tag within which the `html template` is loading.  For ex:

```
<ui-view ng-animate-children></ui-view>
```

It worked for me as I was unable to animate `ng-repeat`.  Once I added this `attribute`, the animations began.

Hope this helps. *Good Luck.*