# Angular 1.3.3 - ngAnimate 1.3.3 not adding classes

Tags: css, angularjs, animation, ng-animate

I have an app that I am trying to animate, but I can't seem to figure out why classes are not being added.  I included the script on the page, added the ngAnimate dependency (it allows me to inject $animate so I assume this is a good check to see if it actually loaded?).  My setup is fairly simple which makes this all the more frustrating that it doesn't work. I am trying to animate an ng-repeat.

I left out the vendor prefixes from the keyframes in the interest of keeping the post short, but I do have them in my less file. When I inspect the element in chrome and manually add ng-leave as a class it animates as it should, so I'm pretty sure my animation is fine, just ngAnimate is not adding the classes as I expect it to.  I could be missing something in my css file.  The closest thing I can find that I am confused on is this link:

[Installation of ngAnimate Module not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894628/installation-of-nganimate-module-not-working)

It states that ngAnimate will not add the classes unless you don't set the specific CSS rules.  I am confused on whether my &.ng-leave is enough for ngAnimate to pick up on it or do I need to add more?  Also my ng-repeat is in a directive template if that matters. Everything renders on the page fine, just no animation triggers.

I have spent the last several hours looking at any link remotely related to people having this issue and have tried everything I found, but nothing makes it work. Code is below

```
//css
@keyframes rollOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 120deg);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 120deg);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 120deg);
    -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 120deg);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 120deg);
  }
}
.roll-out.ng-leave {
  -webkit-animation: rollOut 5s linear;
  -moz-animation: rollOut 5s linear;
  -o-animation: rollOut 5s linear;
  animation: rollOut 5s linear;
}

//html
<div ng-repeat="item in list track by $index" class="roll-out">
      <div>{{ item }}</div>
</div>


//app.js (loaded correctly?)
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var modules = ['core', 'gui', 'etc'];
    var submodules = ['filter', 'service', 'directive'];
    var libmodules = ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate'];

    modules.forEach(function(module) {
        submodules.forEach(function(sub) {
            angular.module(module + '.' + sub, []);
        });
        angular.module(module, submodules.map(function(a) { return module + '.' + a; }));
    });

    angular.module('myApp', modules.concat(libmodules));

}());
```

Comment: Heads up, there is an `$animate` service available in the AngularJS core that just performs simple DOM operations. So it is not a good way to check if ngAnimate is loaded.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. I added in my app.js to show how I am loading modules. My entire app works, and adding in ngAnimate did not give an error. Other than that I don't know how to tell if it is loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

css:

```
.roll-out.ng-leave {
     opacity: 1;
     transition: all 5s linear;
}

.roll-out.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
     opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 120deg);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 120deg);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 120deg);
    -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 120deg);
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 120deg);
}
```

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list track by $index" class="roll-out">
      <div>{{ item }}</div>
</div
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AD8Priu0C13B6DcClx87?p=preview)

Comment: No it doesn't (in a way). Your plunkr helped me figure out what was wrong though. I was removing items indirectly and updating the display after it was removed, so technically nothing ever "left" the ng-repeat. I can't believe I wasted all afternoon (about 3.5 hours now) trying to figure this out!